# Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: php, ajax, веб-сервер, производительность

Я написал некий веб-интерфейс с большим количеством скриптов, вызываемых через ajax. Писал на локалхосте, потом залил в интернет посмотреть, как будет работать там. Секунд через 15-20 активного "тыканья" по кнопкам, сервер перестал отвечать на запросы, плюнув в меня 503 ошибкой.

Код, как я осознал, действительно получился довольно долговязный. Кроме 1-3 необходимых запросов к бд, ещё 2-3 дополнительных запроса с целью проверить, в праве ли человек совершать данное действие. (из таблицы авторизации вытаскиваем id, потом из таблицы пользователей берём информацию о пользователе, потом в таблице привилегий смотрим полномочия человека...)

**Что можно сделать,** чтобы избежать 503 ошибки в моём случае**?**
Я подумывал в сессию при первой проверке запихать что-то типа `$_SESSION['can_i_do_this']=time()+180;` и делать следующую проверку только через 3 минуты. Но тогда получается, что если в эти три минуты вдруг у человека изменятся привилегии, то какое-то время он будет "сидеть" с неправильными данными, а это не очень хорошо.

Comment: А что за сервер? Посмотрите логи, на чём валится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

503 ошибка - это обычно не хватает ресурсов сервера. Вы, молодой человек, подумайте где слабое место. 
По той информации, что тут описана делать выводы тяжело, можно только давать советы по диагностики проблемы.

1. Если доступна консоль сервера, то
       можно ещё раз попробовать завалить
       сервер и просмотреть вывод top или
       htop при этом.
2. **Обратить внимание,
       не открываются ли файлы, ресурсы и
       т.д. Может что то обрабатывается
       рекурсивно.**
3. Попробуйте вручную
       вскормить sql запросы вашей
       программы с инструкцией explain.
4. Покажите, хоть что то.

Comment: @metoban, бесплатный хостинг Hostinger, логи я искал в первую очередь, не нашёл.  
Рекурсии точно нет.
Всё работает нормально, если "работать медленно". Как я понял, проблема именно в большом количестве запросов. Помнится как-то пару лет назад пытался написать чат на ajax c помощью поллинга (интревал - одна секунда), так столкнулся с той же проблемой. В итоге меня даже забанили на том хостинге)
Я думаю в моей ситуации лучшим решением будет взвалить всю работу на плечи браузера, а потом в конце одним запросом сохранять результат работы.